# angular2 two-way binding doesn't updated as I enter the string

Tags: angular, input, data-binding, ngmodel

I am new to angular2 and I am hoping someone can help me with a basic thing that why my two way binding is not working. I have this super simple code in my html and I have added following in my `module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

in html:
<input [(ngModel)]="username">
<p>Hello {{username}}!</p>
```

The problem that I have is that as I enter a string in the input box the `"Hello {{username}}"` doesn't get updated. But when I just click outside of the input box the `"Hello {{username}}"` will be updated with the entered value.

Please let me know what magic I am missing here :(. thanks

Comment: Do you get an error in the browser console?

Comment: try to create a new `ng app` `ng new my-app` then paste the `html input` in to `app.comonent.html` and see how the rest of the code is different from you app. All working for me in default `ng app`

Comment: Have u declared 'username' in your .ts?? Create a variable in .ts file it will work

Comment: I finally find my answer and apparently the change detection is not kicking off for some reason. So I had to manually call change detection which then binding works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add `ngModelOptions` or `name`

```
<input [(ngModel)]="username" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

or

```
<input [(ngModel)]="username" name="username">
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. none of them works. I really can't figure out why

Comment: This just works, even without `ngModelOptions` or `name` https://plnkr.co/edit/LuPcLfQ8Hzrn3G0qXAYw?p=preview

Comment: You are right, unfortunately in my code base is not working and it needs that extra click to update the string.

Comment: I don't see a way of diagnosing it from here. If you can update the Plunker so that it reproduces your problem, I can have another look.

Comment: I am making a change in a big code base which is in a hybrid state (angularjs and angular). The angular2 component I have will be downgraded to angularjs to be used in the hybrid app. Do you suspect that event detection and binding facing difficulties due to the hybrid app?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any knowledge about Angular1 or using Angular2 components in Angular1

Comment: I am also facing this issue and none of these solutions worked for me. Any suggestions, how to tackle with this issue?

Comment: @WasiF that's an issue with your code. How would we be able to provide support with this information? I'd suggest you create a new question with a http://stackblitz.com example that allows to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @ Günter Zöchbauer I am blocked from asking questions. Can you help me get out of it so that I can post a question.

Comment: Sorry, don't have any superpower on SO.

Comment: somehow I created [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqkven) have a look at it, check output in console and in the view. You'll find the error in console window only.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
For me the solution was using "string" as datatype rather then "String".